# How can i set post_per_page in my taxonamy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

```
<?php
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'terms' => array('ALL'),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT_IN'
            ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media',
            'terms' => array('news', 'events'),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT_IN'
            ),
        );
                                        query_posts($myquery);

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<div>
<php the-title(); ?>
</div>
<php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yyyy... What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "post count in my taxonomy"?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$my_query['posts_per_page'] = 10;` (or some other number) before `query_posts` call.

But I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Hi Krzysiek Dróżdż, thank you for your replay. it's not working, i updated the question.please check

Comment: What is not working? How did you add it? As I can see, you don't know PHP very well - am I correct?